# Paged ldap_search in OpenLDAP to get around size limit?

Tags: c, ldap, openldap

We are currently in the process of migrating from an aged proprietary directory service to OpenLDAP.
Today we ran into the problem that [ldap_search_ext_s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366972%28VS.85%29.aspx) or ldapsearch in general does not return any results, if the number of entries, which were to be returned by the current search, would hit a certain limit.

Unfortunately setting the size limit higher in the LDAP server configuration might just  postpone the problem, as we have a really big database and our update mechanism, which runs every morning, has to performe huge queries.

In the MSDN documentation I noticed that there is a mechanism to perform a [paged search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366973%28VS.85%29.aspx), which would allow me to get around the size limitation.
Apparently this is also specified in an [RFC draft from 1996](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-howes-ldap-api-00) but hasn't been finalized (yet)?

Anyway, since I'm not working on a Windows-Box I have to use the OpenLDAP API, which doesn't seem to provide that mechanism (at least I couldn't find it on their [search page](http://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi))

Which brings me to my question: Do you have an idea what I could do, to solve that problem in an elegant manner?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenLDAP supports paged result retrieval via `ldap_create_page_control ()` and friends. [Here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=ssw_ibm_i_74/apis/ldap_create_page_control.htm) is a description and sample code. If that doesn't help I may be able to provide excerpts from production code.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into that right on monday! (Up until now I just gave up on that topic and we increased the query limit...)

Comment: I finally came around to implement it. It Works. Thank you very much :)

Comment: the link is now broken.

Comment: Looks like it moved to [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=ssw_ibm_i_74/apis/ldap_create_page_control.htm).

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue using ldap_create_page_control with ldap_search_ext_s, my ldap library implementation was using LDAP version 2 by default and it looks it's supported for version 3+. It was returning "Not supported" from ldap_search_ext_s() before I set LDAP to version 3.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around the size limitation using [ldap_control_paged_result](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-control-paged-result.php)

ldap_control_paged_result is used to Enable LDAP pagination by sending the pagination control. The below function worked perfectly in my case.

```
    function retrieves_users($conn)
    {
        $dn        = 'ou=,dc=,dc=';
        $filter    = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(sn=*))";
        $justthese = array();

        // enable pagination with a page size of 100.
        $pageSize = 100;

        $cookie = '';

        do {
            ldap_control_paged_result($conn, $pageSize, true, $cookie);

            $result  = ldap_search($conn, $dn, $filter, $justthese);
            $entries = ldap_get_entries($conn, $result);

            if(!empty($entries)){
                for ($i = 0; $i < $entries["count"]; $i++) {
                    $data['usersLdap'][] = array(
                            'name' => $entries[$i]["cn"][0],
                            'username' => $entries[$i]["userprincipalname"][0]
                    );
                }
            }
            ldap_control_paged_result_response($conn, $result, $cookie);

        } while($cookie !== null && $cookie != '');

        return $data;
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

Use AD or Novell's eDirectory? ;)

Comment: All kinds of Active Directory (including the one used in domain controllers, and also standalone ones like ADAM and AD LDS) normally have a limit of 1000 results returned per request, so if you expect your query to return more results than that, you have to use some kind of paged search: either via Simple Paged Results control, or via Virtual List View (VLV) control.